# DXA version 2.2.18. Upgrade to Jackson 2.13.4 results in the exception: Cannot get a source converter for class java.util.LinkedHashMap

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa2.2

Using DXA version 2.2.18. When I tried to upgrade to Jackson 2.13.4, getting the following exception. Jackson 2.10.0 works fine. Does DXA not support Jackson 2.13.4?:

> [http-nio-8080-exec-10] WARN
> c.s.d.t.m.c.GenericSemanticModelDataConverter - Cannot get a source
> converter for class java.util.LinkedHashMap [http-nio-8080-exec-10]
> ERROR c.s.w.c.i.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl - Exception while getting
> field data....
> com.sdl.webapp.tridion.fields.exceptions.UnsupportedTargetTypeException:
> Unsupported target class: java.util.LinkedHashMap
> at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.GenericSemanticModelDataConverter.getSourceConverter(GenericSemanticModelDataConverter.java:82)
> at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.converter.GenericSemanticModelDataConverter.convert(GenericSemanticModelDataConverter.java:72)
> at com.sdl.dxa.tridion.mapping.impl.DefaultSemanticFieldDataProvider.getFieldData(DefaultSemanticFieldDataProvider.java:138)

Answer (score 0):

It is likely a breaking change between Jackson 2.10.5 used in DXA 2.2 and Jackson 2.13.4. I see the DXA team has upgraded to 2.13.4 2 months ago, but I don't think they have released this yet. You should ask them, for example by creating an issue in the DXA java repository on Github (https://github.com/RWS/dxa-web-application-java).